# sharepoint CAML query in Ascending order

Tags: sharepoint-designer, caml-query, caml-designer

we have webpart that fetch the data from the sharepoint list

```
camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View></View>);
```

now i am trying to do sort the display by enddate (ascending order)

```
camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='EndDate' /></OrderBy></Query></View>");
```

i am using the above caml query but it is not working , can you please help me out.

my code

```
function GetCTItems() {
        var context = new SP.ClientContext();
        var oList = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('sharepointLst');
        var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
        //camlQuery.Query=("<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='EndDate' Ascending = 'FALSE'/></OrderBy>");
        camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='EndDate' Ascending='True' /></OrderBy></Query></View>");      
        var CTCollection = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
        context.load(CTCollection);
        context.executeQueryAsync(function () {
            var htmlString = "";
            var listItemEnumerator = CTCollection.getEnumerator();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Ascending='True'` as the following

```
camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='EndDate' Ascending='True' /></OrderBy></Query></View>");
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67303/discussion-on-answer-by-m-qassas-sharepoint-caml-query-in-ascending-order).

Answer (score 0):

To get the correct CAML, create a view that meets your criteria in SharePoint on the list and then you could use SharePoint Client Browser at https://github.com/bramdejager/spcb/blob/master/README.md to get the actual CAML for the view.

Comment: i am using CAML builder , <Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='EndDate' /></OrderBy> this is working in CAML builder, but not in code i don't know why